# `apply` the `rowMeans` across multiple sets of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

Sorry, people, I can't see the forest for the trees. I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. I want, e.g., the mean for every unit (potentially the `rowMeans`) of a subset of variables in a matrix (or potentially a dataframe) in `R`. I would like to select the columns using an indexing vector as in `tapply`, which I called `a1` in the example below.

```
> set.seed(23958)
> (dat <- matrix(sample(0:3, 10, replace = TRUE), ncol = 5))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    3    0    2    1
[2,]    2    1    1    2    1

> set.seed(6112)
> (a1 <- sample(1:2, 5, replace = TRUE))
[1] 1 1 2 2 1
```

The solution in this example should look like this, but of course I would like to do it in a more comprehensive way. I was thinking I should use a function from the `apply` family, but I could not find out which one.

```
> cbind(rowMeans(dat[, a1 == 1]), rowMeans(dat[, a1 == 2]))
         [,1] [,2]
[1,] 2.000000  1.0
[2,] 1.333333  1.5
```

Comment: You should set a seed to make your example reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `tapply` here:

```
do.call(rbind,
          tapply(seq_len(ncol(dat)),a1,
           function(i)rowMeans(dat[,i])))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `t`ranspose your data, you can use `by`:

```
t(do.call(rbind,by(t(dat),a1,colMeans)))
          1   2
V1 2.000000 1.0
V2 1.333333 1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `aggregate` function:

```
t(aggregate(t(dat), list(a1), mean))
```